# Setting jQuery Event switch between resizable and draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a div box on my screen. I want the user to resize the jquery box whenever they want AND cancel the jquery draggable event at the same time and vis versa. I'm using a plugin for the draggable section and it is glitching when I resize the box so the solution would be to cancel the draggable event while I resize it. I tried this code below but it doesn't work and I know the logic isn't correct. My question is how would I fix this to make it work?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>

<script src="js/easing.js" ></script>
<script src="js/animadrag.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs
/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="body">
    <div class="move"></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" >

$('.move').resizable();     

$('.move').on('hover',function (event) {
//something, although I don't know what, should be put here to cancel resizable
    $('.move').animaDrag({ 
                speed: 150, 
                interval: 120, 
                easing: null, 
                cursor: 'move', 
                boundary: '.body',
                grip: null,  
                overlay: true           
});     

</script>
```

Here is the working jsbin example. http://jsbin.com/obovof/2/edit

Comment: `I'm using a plugin for the draggable section and it is glitching when I resize the box so the solution would be to cancel the draggable event while I resize it.` Have you tried contacting the makers of the plug-in or read their documentation, assuming there is any to try and find out how to cancel the draggable event? Specially when 3rd-party libraries are involved it would more than help if you can provide a fidde on jsFiddle.net, referencing the required libraries and add the relevant code to demo the issue.

Comment: The plugin was made awhile back and no updates have been made in the past 2 years. I will create a fiddle though of it and post it on here.

Comment: You are much better of then to implement jQuery UI's sortable and/or draggable instead of some old and most likely unsupported library. http://jqueryui.com/demos/ under `interactions` you see anything from sortable, draggable to resizable and so on.

Comment: Animadrag runs much more smoothly in Firefox than jquery's draggable. I'm willing to take the plugin for this reason.

Comment: @ jason328, that is a good enough reason I suppose, pitty the plugin had no action for 2 years. Hopefully someone here can help out. I have a go myself at it if you can manage to get a fiddle going.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want disable the draggable during the resize. Technically the user will be not able to drag the element during the resize. 
Anyway if you use the jqueryui method draggable instead the animaDrag: you can do it in this way:

```
$('.move').draggable().resizable({
    start: function(e, ui) {$(this).draggable( "disable" )},
    stop: function(e, ui) {$(this).draggable( "enable" )}
});
```

Comment: You're right, but with the plugin the box becomes glitchy and shifts around the screen at random times.

Comment: well on this plugin you have the after, during and before functions where you can disable or enable the draggable

Comment: I'll try that then. Would a `return false` in those functions do it?

Comment: try to use just $(this).draggable("disable");

Comment: I'm still getting the weird glitches. I'll play with this for a couple of mins. I think you lead me on the right track.